# Rails Tutorial: Testing Error (Cannot Load Such File)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Complete beginner here. I've been working through the Hartl Rails tutorial--currently the "Advanced Testing Setup" for the optional exercises in Chapter 3. Though testing was running smoothly beforehand, I'm getting the following error upon running either "rake test" or "guard":

```
LoadError: cannot load such file --
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/config/environment
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10:in `<class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:31:in `create_and_run_single_test'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:17:in `invoke_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:single
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using the standard Gems file from the tutorial:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I'm sure this is not a difficult fix, but thought I might as well ask. Thanks so much!

Comment: The error says that it can't find this file "/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/config/environment". Maybe you deleted or renamed it by mistake? If it was working before it has to be something you have done. In Linux you can see your command history if you type 'history' in your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an error with your `require` statement.

have you added the following code to your `test_helper` file? (Copied from https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-advanced_testing_setup)

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical
  # order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Pay specific attention to this line:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Seems I'd added it to my controller test file rather than test_helper. Looks like it's fixed!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a problem with the require statement as Joel mentioned. Be sure to have a 'guard' installed before 'guard-minitest'.

Add gem 'guard' to to your gem file & run bundle install. I hope it will fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

put this you your gemfile:

```
gem 'guard', '~> 2.13'
```